# Store in-app items data on device

Tags: android, encryption, in-app-purchase

I want to add in-app purchase functionality to my application, and I would like to know what is the recommended way to store the available count of a product (for example 100 coins).

A user with root access can:

- access/manipulate unencrypted data that the application store (so he can change the
  number of coins).
- save the encryped (or obfuscated) data, and then later replace it to get back the
  state when he had much more coins

So even with encryption, it is relatively easy to cheat. My questios are:

- should I go any further than encrytion? (does it worth the effort?)
- is it common that users abuse this?
- is there a better way to store item counts?
- what is the practise?

Comment: Better to save in server

Comment: And what if the user goes offline? I still have to store it locally to allow offline mode.

Comment: Saving these data locally is always vulnerable with root access.

Comment: I know. That is why I have asked this question:) I have to store it locally, its a regular mobile application. Offline mode is a must.

Comment: Why not store them on the server and not allow purchases to take place while offline?

Comment: It's a good idea, but not acceptable if most of the functions cost coins. (In my case it would nearly equal to online mode only.)

Comment: If your application is a game then store the game state and in-app state in a single file if that is possible. In general, mix the current state of your application in to the data blob where the in-app state is stored. The idea is if that blob with in-app goodies still unspent will be reverted then the app state will reset to that previous state too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your game-world currency locally and let transactions occur locally without network connection, but when the user reconnects to the internet, reconcile the local coins with what the server shows as purchased.

Basically, when you have a network connection, download any purchased in-app products from Google. Check your inventory, then consume whatever products should be reduced based on what the user did while offline. After doing this, if there's a discrepancy between the local total and what the server shows (after consuming), then flag it as a potential hack. Otherwise, you're good (everything balances).

When using consumable in-app products like this (which it sounds like you're trying to do), there's really no completely offline way to do it. You're relying on Google's in-app billing services, so you have to check their servers from time-to-time to reconcile/refresh the purchased inventory. From Google's [in-app billing documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html):

> To record a purchase consumption, send the `consumePurchase` method to
>   the In-app Billing service and pass in the `purchaseToken` String value
>   that identifies the purchase to be removed. The `purchaseToken` is part
>   of the data returned in the `INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA` String by the Google
>   Play service following a successful purchase request. In this example,
>   you are recording the consumption of a product that is identified with
>   the purchaseToken in the token variable.
>
> `int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, getPackageName(), token);`
>
> Warning: Do not call the `consumePurchase` method on the main thread.
>   Calling this method triggers a network request which could block your
>   main thread. Instead, create a separate thread and call the
>   `consumePurchase` method from inside that thread.
>
> It's your responsibility to control and track how the in-app product
>   is provisioned to the user. For example, if the user purchased in-game
>   currency, you should update the player's inventory with the amount of
>   currency purchased.

As for how to store and manage inventory while offline, the ways you've mentioned sound fine. Encrypting doesn't hurt, but likely unnecessary as long as you reconcile with Google at reasonable intervals. Only a very small percentage of people actually try to exploit apps. Most users don't root, and for those that do, most actually have no clue how to pull off these exploits. If you're still worried about it, yes, go ahead and encrypt. That should be sufficient enough of a deterrence to keep the vast majority of your users honest.

Comment: Yeah @hungryghost, good point here. I don't think you should bother with a very few cheaters, as the great majority of people won't even try to hack or take advantage of in-app hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Even you encrypt your password with a String while offline and store locally, those who put some more effort will still be able to reverse-engineer your app and find out the String to decrypt the password. Obfuscating your app is just to make hackers to work harder, but not impossible.  Otherwise, hackers won't exist at all.